# How to use redirect URI with OAuth2.0 and Box for my Android application?

Tags: android, box-api, box, boxapiv2

I have an Android application that makes use of the Box sdk. The Box functionality has been broken for a while as I'm finally getting around to updating to the most recent version of the sdk. When I try to authenticate a user from my application using the `OAuthActivity` I'm informed that "error: redirect_uri_missing".

When I view my application on the Box developers page, I see that it expects me to enter a redirect uri in the OAuth2 Parameters section. But, despite searching for an answer, I'm thoroughly confused as to what to enter here?

EDIT:

Based on the below API, it would seem that I could use the below method to authenticate to box without a redirect uri set. However, when I use it as follows, I get: "Errror: insecure_redirect_uri".

```
OAuthActivity.createOAuthActivityIntent(activity, KEY, SECRET, false, "http://localhost");
```

> 

```
/**
     * Create intent to launch OAuthActivity. Notes about redirect url parameter: If you already set redirect url in <a
     * href="https://cloud.app.box.com/developers/services">box dev console</a>, you should pass in the same redirect url or use null for redirect url. If you
     * didn't set it in box dev console, you should pass in a url. In case you don't have a redirect server you can simply use "http://localhost".
     * 
     * @param context
     *            context
     * @param clientId
     *            your box client id
     * @param clientSecret
     *            your box client secret
     * @param allowShowRedirectPage
     *            Whether you want to load/show redirected page after OAuth flow is done.
     * @param redirectUrl
     *            redirect url, if you already set redirect url in <a href="https://cloud.app.box.com/developers/services">box dev console</a>, leave this null
     *            or use the same url, otherwise this field is required. You can use "http://localhost" if you don't have a redirect server.
     * @return
     */
    public static Intent createOAuthActivityIntent(final Context context, final String clientId, final String clientSecret,
        final boolean allowShowRedirectPage, String redirectUrl)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the confusion, some of this documentation is out of date. You should use `https://localhost` as the redirect URI on your application configuration page (which can be found [here](https://cloud.app.box.com/developers/services/)). We no longer allow insecure redirect URIs, meaning that they must use HTTPS. Once the redirect URI is set for you app, you can leave the `redirectUrl` parameter null.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter `http://127.0.0.1` or `https://127.0.0.1` (loopback address)